# Python Selenium how to grab alert thank you after submit form?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I trying below code to send a message in wordpress contact 7 page

I have tried below code

```
email = driver.find_element_by_name('email')
email.send_keys("test@mail.com")
message = driver.find_element_by_name('message')
message.send_keys("test message")

driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('form').submit()


html_source = driver.page_source

WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

if "Thank you" in html_source:
    print("Received thank you")
else:
    print("Not received")
```

After submit form I have gotten a alert message like below

[image]

How can I grab this alert message ?

Answer (score 1):

if it is in a div then you can do this

```
my_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[text()='Thanks you for your message. It has been sent.']")
```

You can add wait so the site can return this message on the send button before adding this line of code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use BeautifulSoup to do this. In your example you are looking for thank you but it's spelled as Thank you.

You should either look for Thank you, or put the pagesource to lowercase and search for thank you.

```py
if "thank you" in html_source.lower():
    print("Received thank you")
else:
    print("Not received")
```

Comment: That is typing mistake, I have tried with 'Thank you' , after submit form this alert message appearing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are storing the HTML source which is just a string value, waiting 10 seconds, and then checking in that *original* string again.

A simple solution would be to simply get the `html_source` after the wait instead of before the wait.

```py
# We don't want to get the source before waiting, as it won't contain any updated
# html generated via JS!
# html_source = driver.page_source

WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# Get the HTML after waiting for JS to add the alert in HTML
html_source = driver.page_source

if "Thank you" in html_source:
    print("Received thank you")
else:
    print("Not received")
```

Even better, using the `WebDriverWait().until()` function to ensure that the element is loaded instead of relying on some amount of time (this can also be quicker if the element is loaded faster than 10 seconds).

```py
alert_loaded = lambda d: return "Thank you" in d.page_source

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(alert_loaded)

# Element has the alert in the webpage, do stuff with it...
```